# Publish files online with joomla for download

Tags: file, joomla, download

I would like to publish some files to be downloaded through my joomla-made site, but I can`t find the tool to do it. How can I achieve this? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is two Joomla components that you can use to publish files with:

1. [Phoca Download](http://www.phoca.cz/phocadownload/)
2. [Remository](http://remository.com)

I have tried both and prefer Phoca Download, but you may come to a different conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

there is another option. i found a nifty extension that alows you to attach files to your articles.

Attachments for content articles

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-&-documentation/downloads/3115/details

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [DocMan](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/82/details), which is quite a commonly used document management and download system for Joomla.  I use it with the DocLink extension, which makes it easy to link to your files in DocMan from your Joomla article editor.